# Reference request: Kleiman's proof of Snapper's Lemma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, intersection-theory, sheaf-cohomology, hilbert-polynomials

On page 4 of Nitin Nitsure's paper [Construction of Hilbert and Quot Schemes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590), the author refers to the fact that Hilbert polynomials are indeed polynomials as

> a special case of Snapper's Lemma, see "An Intersection Theory for Divisors (preprint 1994)" by Steven Kleiman for a proof.

Kleiman's paper (or book?) mentioned by Nitsure must have either changed its title, never gone into publication, or elsehow disappeared, since I am unable to find it. Does anybody have a link, or an alternative source for the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proof by Kleiman can be found in ‘‘[Toward a Numerical Theory of Ampleness](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970447.pdf)’’. I suspect it's the intended proof, although the paper is from around 30 years before the cited 1994 preprint.

Answer (score 8):

Note that Nitsure's paper is part of the book [*FGA Explained*](http://www.ams.org/books/surv/123/). There is a proof of Snapper's lemma in Theorem B.7 of Appendix B ("Basic intersection theory" by Kleiman) in the same book. Kleiman's part of the book can also be found independently on arXiv: [0504020](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504020) and contains the relevant appendix.